# ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am running Elasticsearch and kibana, I am not sure of the status of my elasticsearsh cluster (if its red, yellow, or green) but it seems I need to get a token generated by elasticsearch as in the screenshot when I ran `bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token --scope kibana` from the right directory it errors out `ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster.`.

[image]

Comment: What happened when you started elasticsearch ? Is there anything in the logs that indicated that elastisearch didn’t start correctly ? 

You don’t _need to use_ the enrollment token, you can also configure elastisearch and kibana manually, this is just supposed to be easier. The actual problem you are facing is that elastisearch didn’t start correctly and if you can figure out why, you can move forward. Please check the logs for elastisearch and maybe update the question with relevant error messages

Answer (score 17):

According Ioannis Kakavas in [discuss.elastic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-reset-the-elastic-and-kibana-user-password/306464/8), "CLI tools extending BaseRunAsSuperuserCommand should only connect to the local node". When I run in a local node, it works. But when I run in the elasticsearch container in a cluster, it doesn't work. The solution was execute the `elastic-search-reset-password` and `elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token` scripts, respectively, like this (inside the elasticsearch container):

`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -i -u elastic --url https://localhost:9200`

`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana --url https://localhost:9200`

Comment: are you using docker containers to run your elasticsearch?

Comment: @Mahlatse yes. I'm using docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.3.2 image.

Comment: this helped me reset credentials after i lost them thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, and I just redid the process - unzipped the ES and kibana zip files again, and ran bin/elasticsearch in the newly created directory. Look for a message that is encapsulated in a formatted box that contains both the password for the elastic user, and the enrollment token for Kibana (the token is only valid for 30 minutes). This message will only appear once, the first time you run elasticsearch.

I proceeded to run bin/kibana for Kibana and configured it in the browser, and everything worked out from there. Hope this helps!

Comment: great that this worked for you, it still not working for me after re-installations. i noticed that elasticsearch.yml file changed after running elasticseach for the first time

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact issue:

```
$ sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic

ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster.
```

But after I restart the elasticsearch service:

`$ sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch.service`
then it works:

```
This tool will reset the password of the [elastic] user to an autogenerated value.
The password will be printed in the console.
Please confirm that you would like to continue [y/N]y


Password for the [elastic] user successfully reset.
New value: xxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command:

```
"elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana --url "https://localhost:9200""
```

I got the same error and was able to generate the token after hitting this url. Just make sure that you are inside bin folder of elasticsearch. For me the bin folder is located at "C:\Users<username>\Downloads\Apps\elasticsearch-8.7.0\bin".

Also if you are not using localhost you can replace it with the ip address(e.g. 127.0.0.1 for localhost)

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem described above and even with the --url parameter it just showed me a different error (ERROR: Unable to create an enrollment token. Elasticsearch node HTTP layer SSL configuration Keystore doesn't contain any PrivateKey entries where the associated certificate is a CA certificate, with exit code 73).

For me it now worked by directly creating certificates via elasticsearch-certutil. Here are the commands I used:

sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --name  --ca .p12 --ca-pass  --dns "" --out /tmp/_http.p12 --pass

sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --name  --ca .p12 --ca-pass  --dns "" --out /tmp/__transport.p12 --pass

Then I mentioned the certs in the elasticsearch.yml in the security settings and added the passwords to the elasticsearch keystore. The rights, ownership and group membership of the certs may still need to be set to the user of the service (elasticsearch)

I hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

- Make sure that you have enough disk space.
- Your VPN might be causing the issue.

Comment: In my case, it was the VPN which caused this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I also feel the same, VPN seems to be causing the issue, how do we resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and changed http.host to 127.0.0.1 then restart the Elasticsearch, then it goes well.

By the way, Elasticsearch version 8.8.2

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a Mac, and Orbstack was running in the background so I closed it and tried this command

```bash
./elasticsearch-reset-password -i -u elastic
```

and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score -2):

The enrollment Token will be present in the terminal itself. You just need to scroll up till you find it when you are installing.

The reason for the error - `ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster` is due to the fact that **Elastic** has not been installed yet and running that command is like calling a function without defining it.

Comment: Installing elasticsearch has become such a pain to me

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a blood-sucking process. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: it's was working yesterday now I start the `elastic search` today I am getting this error `Failed to determine the health of the cluster`

Comment: Nope. installed from deb package, no token presented.